# Formatting ValidationError in View with Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, validationerror

I don't manage to access to the ValidationError message from my view.
The only output I manage to get in my view is :

```
[ValidationError(username,Too short, sorry ;),[6])]
[ValidationError(password,Confirmation password doesn't match,[])]
```

I would like to output only the error message : "Too short, sorry ;)" and "Confirmation password doesn't match".

The workaround I found is by calling a specific field from the form and then access to the error message :

```
@form("password").error.map(_.message).getOrElse("")
```

Thanks,

My view register.scala.html :

```
@if(form.hasErrors) {
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-danger col-lg-6 text-center">
       @for((key, vamlue) <- form.errors){
         @value<br />
       }
   </div>
</div>
}
```

My controller :

```
public static Result registerSubmit(){
        Form<User> registerForm = form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
        String passwordConfirmation = registerForm.field("passwordConfirmation").value();

        if(!registerForm.field("password").valueOr("").equals(passwordConfirmation)){
            ValidationError e = new ValidationError("password", "Confirmation password doesn't match");
            registerForm.reject(e);
        }

        if (registerForm.hasErrors()){
            // Handle Error
            return badRequest(register.render(registerForm));
        } else {
            // Check if all data are fine    
            // TODO : Redirect to Login Page
            return ok(register.render(registerForm));
        }
    }
```

And finally the model User.java :

```
@Required
@MinLength(6)
String username;

@Required
@Email
String email;

@Required
@MinLength(6)
String password;
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: I was trying to print only the readable error message, not the ValidationError object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to collect all your form errors and display them at the top of the form. I think this is the code block you want to be using in your HTML template

```
@if(form.hasErrors) {
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-danger col-lg-6 text-center">
      @for(entry <- form.errors.entrySet){
        @for(error <- entry.getValue){
          @error.message <br/>
        }
      }
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

If you convert the `form.errors` map from a Java map to a Scala Map you can make your code block a little more concise than nested for-loops, but this should do the job.